# Daily overview of traffic with information on what processes consumed how much of the traffic on a Linux server

Tags: linux-networking, traffic, network-traffic

By the end of the day (or week/month) I would like to have an overview of all processes which used the network with information about how much traffic was generated by each of those processes for that particular period of time on a Linux server:

1. How much traffic was used in total in a given period?
2. Which processes used how much (in MB or percentage) of it?

I use `vnstat` to show me how much traffic is consumed on a server - I find it very handy - what I would like to have is something like `vnstat` showing not only a combined overview of all traffic, but also which process used how much of it.

Maybe there's some tool around there or maybe someone has an idea of how to tackle this issue by writing a script - I'm open to any suggestions on how to get that overview.

Answer (score 1):

I think Datadog might be what you are looking for. Datadog is very rich and according to Gartner one of the market leaders. It also allows you to create custom dashboards. But it also offers a lot more and comes with a price. I'm not not affiliated to Datadog by the way.

You could also use nethogs and output it to a file and analyze it with awk

```
sudo nethogs -t | tee network_logs.txt
cat network_logs.txt | awk '{ total += $2; process[$NF] += $2 } END { print "Total: " total " KB"; for (p in process) print p ": " process[p] " KB" }'
```